# Send Airdrop from Android

Tags: stock-android

Is there any way to send files from an Android phone via Apple's Airdrop to an iPhone? I'm not looking for an alternative system, just want to mess with some colleagues who have iPhones. Currently running CM14.1 with root/xposed.

Thanks in advance.